# Graph Lifecycle Notifications Not registering correct endpoint

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to us the Lifecycle events within the Graph Beta API using code like this:

```
var subscription = new Subscription
{
     Resource = $"users/{userObjectId}/mailFolders('{resource}')/messages",
     ChangeType = "created,updated",
     NotificationUrl = notificationWebHookUrl,
     LifecycleNotificationUrl = lifecycleNotificationWebHookUrl,
     ClientState = clientState,
     ExpirationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow + new TimeSpan(0, 0, 4200, 0),
 };
```

However, even though I have supplied a different LifecycleNotificationUrl to the NotificationUrl, the initial requests to perform the validate request only go to the NotificationUrl endpoint not the LifecycleNotificationUrl endpoint. I have checked and I am definitely supplying different endpoint urls.
I am using 2 separate Azure Functions with Http triggers as the endpoints.
Also to note is that I am using ngrok for exposing my localhost Azure functions.
I understand that if you do not supply a LifecycleNotificationUrl that this is the behaviour that you should expect, but I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We currently have an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/9032) where the validation code is sending two validation requests to the `notificationUrl` and none to the `lifecycleNotificationUrl`. This is something we're trying to address, hopefully shortly. I suggest you follow this issue to get notified of any update on the matter.

Besides that, once the validation is passed, lifecycle notifications will get delivered to your `lifecycleNotificationUrl` and not your `notificationUrl`.